# When would a successful US Presidential impeachment go into effect?

Tags: united-states, impeachment

Assuming a hypothetical US President has been impeached by the House and had the charges confirmed by two-thirds of the Senate:

When does the Vice-President take over? Immediately upon the Senate vote results being declared?

Does the old POTUS need to find a place to sleep that night?  Does the custodian of The Football need to run from the President's side to the VP's?
Does the old POTUS get to issue any pardons?

This situation would be unlike Inauguration Day. There could be real uncertainty, up until Senate voting closes, as to whether any change would take place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constitution states

> The President, Vice President and all civil Officers of the United States, shall be removed from Office on Impeachment for, and Conviction of, Treason, Bribery, or other high Crimes and Misdemeanors.

This means that the President is president until the moment that the Senate convicts, and is not President thereafter. Until the moment of conviction they have all the usual powers of President, and after they have none.

Details like "where does the convicted President sleep" would be dealt with on a case by case basis. It would be within the powers of the incoming President to authorise the impeached president to spend the night at the White House, until their affairs were in order.

The "nuclear football" goes with the President, but the VP has their own "football" (in case the President is incapacitated in a nuclear attack). The contents of the briefcases containing the nuclear codes would be sorted out in the following days and when a new VP was appointed., but at no time would America not have the ability to fire her weapons.

The impeached President doesn't get to issue pardons after he has been convicted. The incoming President can issue pardons, and can pardon the impeached President for any criminal charges (as Ford pardoned Nixon after the latter's resignation)

The handover of power would be fairly straightforward. Certainly it would a lot clearer than if a President dies in office. After the Kennedy assassination and after the Reagan shooting there were periods of confusion. These were unexpected.  During an impeachment trial, the likelihood of conviction could be known in advance.

If a President were impeached and there was a likelyhood of conviction, much of their influence would be lost, and there would be a period during which all their time would be spent on fighting impeachment. They wouldn't be able to advance their policies in Congress (especially against a congress that had voted to remove them from power) They would have all the constitutional rights of President (including the granting of pardons) but little of the influence or soft-power.

Comment: Formally that's correct; but it's likely that in such an event he would become a lame-duck president.

Comment: No, there would be no lame duck period. They are President until conviction, and they are not President after.

Comment: @JamesK And a lame duck is president until he's no longer President.  He's still a lame duck.  I believe Mozibur's saying that in the span between impeachment and conviction he'd be a lame duck in much the same way. There's not much in the way of constitutional mandates on how quickly and soon the Senate holds its trial, or even how; other than the Chief Justice presiding over a president's impeachment, and the need for a 2/3 majority, the Senate makes whatever rules it wants to.

Comment: Assume the Vice President and the President both go to the Senate to witness the trial.  Let us say that the President carried a pen and a notebook.  The President is convicted.  Before and after conviction the President can be seen scribbling in the Presidential notebook.  Later examination of the notebook reveals that it contains a number of pardons.  How would you determine which pardons were issued before conviction (valid) and which were post-conviction (invalid)?

Comment: @JamesK: I find it hard to believe that a president can carry on normally with an impeachment process hanging over his head; the only situation which was remotely like this in the modern era was with President Nixon; and what happened there? The loss of confidence there was so catastrophic he resigned rather than carry on.

Comment: As far as the "football" goes, see my answer [over here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/11000/2130): The VP has their own football, which is just a communication device, so there'd be no need to "run it over".  All that would need to happen is that the President's authentication codes would be invalidated, so they could no longer issue any relevant orders.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: But if matters have proceeded to the point where impeachment is a real possibility, there's going to be a drastic loss of confidence anyway.  I think it really depends on the personality of the President.  A realist would probably resign, as Nixon did.  An egotist (who shall remain nameless) only tenuously in contact with reality probably would claim the impeachment & conviction were "fake news", and would have to be carried out kicking & screaming by Secret Service agents.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I see what you're saying. I thought you meant a lame duck period *after*  conviction.  Yes, a President that was fighting impeachement, and especially one who was likely to be convicted would have a lot of distractions, but see my answer to https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/27053/did-bill-clinton-still-have-his-presidential-powers-after-his-impeachment-by-the Clinton continued to be President between impeachment and his Senate trial.

Comment: This answer while informative does contain the error that Nixon was impeached, He was not. He may and could have been, possibly but we will never know for sure since he resign before it could happen. The famous pardon is to stop the further prosecution of citizen Nixon since he was no longer president. I must also include that Presidents are above the law from the judiciary and common law enforcement and are only answerable to congress who may convict him for anything they want whether it is a law or not.

Comment: @FrankCedeno A President being "above the law" as you state is hardly a matter of surety.  Bill Clinton was not above the law in the civil trials brought against him during his presidency.  A criminal proceeding against a sitting President has never been tested, though Nixon got close before resigning. He might be immune to being charged for acts committed *while* president as *part of his duties*, but he's not immune to civil acts before his term, and might not be immune to criminal acts before or unrelated to his duties. The Supreme Court hasn't rule on such things yet.

Comment: @FrankCedeno I was careful not to say that Nixon was impeached. I said that a incoming president could pardon a President that had been impeached and convicted (to prevent further criminal prosecution, they can't overturn the senate conviction) As an example I gave Ford's pardoning of Nixon, who resigned.  Whether a sitting president can face criminal charges while in office is unclear and not part of the original question. I edited for clarity